# Are code examples a requirement for asking questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, downvoting

I recently asked a question on the Salesforce stackexchange which had to do with a general use pattern between apex controllers and lightning components - no code examples were provided, because no code exists, I just wanted an explanation. And yet my question was downvoted because I didn't provide code.

How can I ask general questions, ones that don't require code examples, without my question being downvoted?

EDIT: [Here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/221556) is the question I'm referring to. Added per request.

Comment: are you expecting more answers ?

Answer (score 9):

**No, but it can help a lot.**

All we need are questions that are specific and can be answered with relative transparant certainty. Ideally in combination with what was already tried and failed.

Words can sometimes not be the best tool to describe code, if you'd need a wall of text to describe a scenario some code snippets can make a lot of difference in helping us understand a question fast and clearly. While I'd thus consider it in your bestinterest to make questions clearly understandable, I wouldn't believe in a community that makes code snippets required before they answer questions.

---

But **please do not use your questions as a conversation vehicle** it is not the place to add remarks on downvotes or comments and suggestions made by other members of the community.

**The stackexchange model allows and encourages community edits and votes to enhance and guide towards more quality** to help others with similar or identical questions to profit from your experience and question. If you can't handle that this isn't the place to ask your questions.

I've reopend the question because it appears a clear yes/no question for anyone experienced in Lightning Development and a good answer was given. **Let's move forward now**.